# C# Pass entity property to a function to use in LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, linq, .net-core

Imagine I have a class like this:

```
public class BaseRepo<T> where T : class
{
    private readonly DbSet<T> table;

    public BaseRepo(MyDbContext context)
    {
        this.table = context.Set<T>();
    }
}
```

I want to implement the following logic in to this class.

```
string GenerateUniqueStringFor(PropertyName)
{
    string val = string.Empty;    

    do
    {
        val = GenerateRandomString();
    }
    while (this.table.FirstOrDefault(x => x.PropertyName == val) is not null);

    return val;
}
```

The problem is I don't know how to pass Property/PropertyName. The ideal way for calling it would be:

```
string val = _myRepo.GenerateUniqueStringFor(x => x.PropertyName);
```

Comment: Assuming _myRepo is a collection, you may be able to use `_myRepo.Select(x => GenerateUniqueStringFor(x.PropertyName))`

Comment: @Tristan _myRepo is a class that inherits from BaseRepo<Model>

Comment: Are you trying to generate dummy data, assign every string property on an object to have random junk in?

Comment: @CaiusJard Well, not dummy but `unique`, and the purpose is to fill some fields (token for example) to a unique string in the same table.

Comment: Alternative approach for generating unique string without loops or property pickers ;) `string GenerateUniqueString() => Guid.NewGuid().ToString();` Ta da :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you can try to pass a delegate `Func`

```
string GenerateUniqueStringFor(Func<T,string> func)
{
    string val = string.Empty;    

    do
    {
        val = GenerateRandomString();
    }
    while (this.table.FirstOrDefault(x => func(x) == val) is not null);

    return val;
}
```

Comment: the generic type argument is not necessary as the method si in the class BaseRepo<T> :)

Comment: Guys, I posted the same exact answer, but I'm not sure it will work in Linq 2 Entities. What do you think about?